# LaTeX renderer for .NET?

Tags: .net, math, latex, tex, renderer

I'm curious as to whether a native .NET renderer for TeX/LaTeX exists. The closest match I have been able to find is a Java implementation, [JMathTeX](http://jmathtex.sourceforge.net/). I am tempted to port this to C#, but before I do so, I would simply like to check whether anyone is aware of a .NET implementation out there.

My current thoughts are to use MiKTeX along with `dvipng` to compile the TeX source and render the generated DVI as a PNG, but I'm still worrying this may incur an unacceptable amount of overhead, not to mention the need to bundle MiKTeX with the given program.

Comment: I find myself wondering why you would do this. Knuth's version is pretty near bug-free (he offers a cash prize for confirmed bugs, and it hasn't been claimed in quite a while). A re-write is not likely to be that good.

Comment: @dmckee: The alternative for rendering within .NET apps is to use a compiler such as MiKTeX and then dvipng to convert it into a PNG. This is a rather indirect method, and I was hoping for something simpler.

Comment: I would expect it to be a better alternative to use the (excellent) pdf[la]tex, as the result would then already be a (relatively) easily displayed format.

Comment: @stephentyrone: dvipng would be an even better option, in my view. Either way, there's still a good deal of overhead involved.

Comment: One use case would be to display mathematical formula inside an application window without installing a hundred MB of latex stuff :-), a lightweight online math formatting. If you decide to go on with porting, I volunteer to help.

Comment: @jdehann: Indeed, that would be the main reason. Bundling MiKTeX with your program isn't terribly convenient. I'm still mulling this over - but thanks for your offer of help - will let you know what I decide. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I'm not mistaken, TeX is written in a dialect of Pascal, and when compiled today it's generally first compiled into standard C, then compiled with a C compiler to produce the final binary. It might be feasible to instead compile the original Pascal code into C# and perhaps write a wrapper around it in C# to be able to use it as a library.

Of course this is a rather large project to take on and is probably overkill for your problem at hand.

Comment: Interesting suggestion. It might be worth compiling to C, and then wrapping in a managed C++/CLI library, I'm thinking.

Comment: Seems you are right. TeX is written in WEB, a variant of Pascal, then compiled into C using http://www.tug.org/web2c/.

Answer (score 6):

[A pure C# implementation of Latex by verybadcat.](https://github.com/verybadcat/CSharpMath)

> This is a C# port of the wonderful iosMath LaTeX engine.
>
> It is now working in most cases. Some examples are below. Ironically
>   enough, the first front end is iOS. However, if you want to add a
>   front end, such as Xamarin.Forms or a Windows environment, it should
>   be possible. You would have to define your own TypesettingContext and
>   write an implementation of IGraphicsContext. The TypesettingContext in
>   turn has several components, including choosing a font. Hopefully, you
>   would not need to touch the core typesetting engine. (If you do, I
>   would consider that a bug.)

[image: CSharpMath example]

Answer (score 5):

This is very overdue, but I thought I'd post a link to a revived and expanded port of the [*WPF-Math*](https://github.com/ForNeVeR/wpf-math) project, which I started not too long after this original question, and still help maintain in a minor capacity. It was originally a port of *JMathTex*, but has since expanded to include a lot more. At the moment, it's in the process of gaining renderers other than WPF.

Answer (score -2):

use this code!!!

```
        const string latex = @"\frac{2+2}{2}";
        const string fileName = @"formula.png";

        File.Open(fileName, FileMode.OpenOrCreate).Close();

        var parser = new WpfMath.TexFormulaParser();
        var formula = parser.Parse(latex);
        var renderer = formula.GetRenderer(WpfMath.TexStyle.Display, 20.0, "Arial");
        var bitmapSource = renderer.RenderToBitmap(0, 0);

        var encoder = new System.Windows.Media.Imaging.PngBitmapEncoder();
        encoder.Frames.Add(System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapFrame.Create(bitmapSource));
        using (var target = new FileStream(fileName, FileMode.Create))
        {
            encoder.Save(target);
        }

        pictureBox2.Image = Image.FromFile(fileName);
```

Comment: you should explain your code and why it should be used, it makes it a lot more useful for future users