# How to render Latex Equations as Images In Asp.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net, performance, latex, processing-efficiency

I have used Mathjax for displaying math Equations, but it takes much time to load. 
I need help in rendering LaTeX Equations as images while loading the page. How to do that in ASP.Net.

Comment: possible duplicate of [render math equations for websites latex](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1158536/render-math-equations-for-websites-latex)

Comment: Also of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1501340/latex-renderer-for-net

Comment: Do you want to load pre rendered images or to render the images on request?

Comment: I want latex equations to be Dynamically converted into images when the page loads.